# Как перевести библиотеку классов из .NET Framework в NET.Core с пакетами NuGet(только для .NetFramework)?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, .net-core, framework

Есть библиотека классов на целевой платформе .NETFramework. Есть исполняемая сборка на целевой платформе .NETCore, в которую нужно включить предыдущую библиотеку классов. Анализ переносимости из .NET на.NETCore данной библиотеки классов дал 100%. Также у данной dll-ки есть пакеты NuGet:

-EntityFramework 6.4 (нет зависимостей, по документации работает как под .Net Framework, так и .Net Core);

-EntityFramework.SqlServerCompact 6.4 (только для .Net Framework ...);

-Extended.Wpf.Toolkit (только для .Net Framework ...);

-Dapper (для .Net Framework 4.0-4.5.1 и .Net Standart 1.3).

Как мне изменить библиотеку классов так, чтобы сохранить по возможности исходные пакеты, но при этом получить совместимость с .NetCore платформой? Заранее спасибо!

Comment: Как вы хотите сохранить пакет, который `только для .Net Framework`?

Comment: Я бы на вашем месте поискал аналоги, прусутствующие для .NET Core. Велика вероятность, что такие же пакеты существуют в .NET Core, но возможно с другими именами. Ну или уже есть, но не очевидно или подождать и скоро будет, например [WPF.Toolkit](https://github.com/xceedsoftware/wpftoolkit/issues/1428). Главное, хорошенько поискать.

Comment: Надо также пояснить, что есть разные версии .NET Core - для asp.net (win\linux\mac),  для десктопа (only win), для консольки (win\linux\mac).

Comment: @tym32167 ну не совсем. Runtime Net Core один и тот же во всех случаях. Он позволяет использовать зависимости из обычного .NET, но с появлением таких зависимостей автоматически пропадает переносимость приложения на другие ОС. Тут все зависит от приложения, если переносимость не нужна - подключаем все что нужно и не ломаем голову, если нужна - то про все, что не является пакетом под Core или NET Standard придется забыть. Некоторых пакетов под Core может и не быть, если, например, не существует версии Sql Server Compact под линукс, то и отдельный пакет для Core вроде как не очень нужен.

Comment: @rdorn я просто посчитал кол версий на [странице загрузки](https://dotnet.microsoft.com/download/dotnet-core/3.1)

Comment: @tym32167 значит я вас неправильно понял, в этом смысле да,сам runtime имеет зависимость от платформы и их много, и иногда даже отличается поведение в отдельных случаях/классах, но в целом для кода приложения оно все таки в основном прозрачно и почти неразличимо

Comment: @rdorn оно скорее всего станет различимо, если скачать `ASP.NET Core Runtime 3.1.2` и попробовать под ним запустить WPF приложение :)

Comment: @tym32167 пока не замечал разницы, ни чего специального не ставил. Как я понял, дистрибутивы отличаются в основном набором компонент интеграции с IIS и другими службами Win, для множества *nix - только спецификой конкретной версии ОС. Не претендую на истину, просто не сталкивался еще с таким, хотя UI под Core уже немного потрогал, правда пока не очень понравилось, может позже доведут до ума

Answer (score 4):

> (только для .Net Framework ...);

Если Вы используете компоненты, которые работают только под .NET, то на .NET Core свою библиотеку Вы один в один никак не перенесёте.

Тут либо отказаться от переноса, либо искать замену, либо выпиливать соответствующий функционал.